# Does "capitalize on" mean "take advantage of a successful exam and not have to take it again along with the unsuccessful one?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to know if the sentence in bold, in the paragraph below, means to take advantage of the successful test, keep its grade and have to only repeat the unsuccessful test? If not, how can I express it?

"Candidates are required to take both the written and oral tests on the same day. If a candidate does not pass one of the two tests (oral or written), **they have the opportunity to capitalize on the successful** test. They can repeat the unsuccessful one within one year."

Comment: It means just that. (Your paragraph lacks closing quotation marks!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means to make the best use of an opportunity, "The tennis player capitalised on his opponent's knee injury by forcing him to run across the court".